# enableAutoActivityTracking not automatically tracking activities?

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

I'm currently initializing my Google Analytics tracker as follows:

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
Tracker mGATracker = analytics.newTracker(context.getString(R.string.ga_code));
mGATracker.setSessionTimeout(300);
mGATracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
```

It works fine for sending custom events and such, though I'm not seeing any auto activity tracking (looking under Behavior -> Events -> Screens in GA). Am I not able to enable this setting in this way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you also make sure you call [`enableAutoActivityReports`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#enableAutoActivityReports%28android.app.Application%29) on `GoogleAnalytics` class? I know that the calls are duplicated but unfortunately, we have not been able to fix this yet. In one of the upcoming versions, we'll remove the need to call this method in two places.

If this answer doesn't work, Can you also make sure that there is some screen name associated with the screens you are using.

If none of the above work, please edit the question and add logs with tag starting with `"GAV"`

Comment: Hopefully will be able to take a look at this later. I don't have time right now. I ended up making explicit screen view calls for the activities.

Comment: @Avi's suggestion of enableAutoActivityReports DID WORK for me. But there was something else affecting the Real-Time data: connectivity. I believe improvements in battery usage make GA 'wait for good connectivity', so until I reach close to my wifi router real-time data doesn't get sent (it does this consistently, tried a few times). I couldn't see this stated anywhere in the docs so I believe it may be useful to someone.