# Is there any code needed in Activity so that ga_autoActivityTracking = true would work for Google Analytics V4

Tags: android, google-analytics

In Google Analytics v3, to auto tracking for `Activity`, we need to have

1. `ga_autoActivityTracking` flag in manifest.xml.
2. GA code in `onStart` and `onStop`

### Google Analytics SDK for Android v3

```
public class myTrackedActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ... // The rest of your onStart() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ... // The rest of your onStop() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
  }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<resources>
  <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXX-Y</string>

  <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

  <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

However, when comes to newer version of Google Analytics v4, (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/), I don't see any code need to be added in `Activity`. From the above documentation, it seems that we only need

1. `ga_autoActivityTracking` flag in manifest.xml.

### Google Analytics SDK v4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <screenName name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.samples.mobileplayground.ScreenviewFragment">
        AnalyticsSampleApp ScreenView
    </screenName>
    <screenName name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.samples.mobileplayground.EcommerceFragment">
        AnalyticsSampleApp EcommerceView
    </screenName>
    <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXX-Y</string>
</resources>
```

However, after tested, it seems that there is no tracking information being automatically sent out from `Activity`.

Is the documentation for Google Analytics V4 missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Step 1

**Add `app_tracker.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-00000000-1</string>

    <!-- catch and report uncaught exceptions from the app -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <screenName name="com.mypackage.NameActivity">Name Activity</screenName>

</resources>
```

### Step 2

**Added `getTracker`**

```
public static Tracker getTracker() {
    if (false == isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        return null;
    }

    if (tracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(MyApplication.instance());
        tracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
    }
    return tracker;
}
```

### Step 3

**Turn on GA during activity startup**

```
public class MyFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Utils.getTracker();
```

Comment: Hi Cheok, can I ask is it whether I just need to execute `getTracker()` once for my activity only and any fragment swapping within the activity will get tracked if there exists a `screenName` in my tracker xml? thanks! :)

Comment: Hi You Qi, if I recall correctly, just need to execute at least one time, then the rest should work as it is.

Comment: where should i place app_tracker.xml ?

Comment: I just place it under `src / main / res / xml / app_tracker.xml`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there appears to be a bug in GAV4. See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691079/google-analytics-for-android-v4-automatic-screen-measurement-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230358/enableautoactivitytracking-not-automatically-tracking-activities).

For devices running API v14 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or later you need to call [`enableAutoActivityReports`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#enableAutoActivityReports%28android.app.Application%29) in addition to setting `ga_autoActivityTracking` to true in your tracker configuration file. I've confirmed this works (that is, screen views do get reported in my Google Analytics console) on a post v14 device.

If you want your app to support devices running pre-API 14 you also have to add calls to [`reportActivityStart`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#reportActivityStart%28android.app.Activity%29) and `reportActivityStop` in `onStart` and `onStop` for all the activities you want to track. I've confirmed this works on a pre v14 device.

I've only tried this with activities, not fragments, and, from one of the links above, it looks like automated screen tracking doesn't work with fragments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code mentioned in Step 4 of the link posted by you in your Activity/Fragment code:

```
   // Get tracker.
    Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
        TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

    // Set screen name.
    // Where path is a String representing the screen name.
    t.setScreenName(path);

    // Send a screen view.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

If you look at the link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens#implementation, there's a sample Fragment snippet given there as well.

**EDIT**:
Sorry, the above information was for manual tracking.
As per this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens#automatic,
if you turn on automatic screen view tracking in your configuration XML, you need to perform only two steps:

- Set the ga_autoActivityTracking parameter in your XML configuration
  file.
- Give each of your Activities a screen name in your XML configuration file.

Comment: but do i need to instantiate a tracker object? otherwhise the tracker would never load the config xml file? (and do if yes - i guess i have to instantiate it in every activity i want to track?)

Comment: Yes, you do need to instantiate a tracker object to load its config file. I followed Google's example of creating a singleton tracker object in a getTracker method of a class inherited from Application. Then I call the getTracker method once, in the onCreate method of the activity for my home screen which is the first screen the user sees. I don't need to call the getTracker method anywhere else in my code to have all the activities tracked.