# What is the use of ga_autoActivityTracking?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I don't understand the use and the difference which ga_autoActivityTracking makes.Even when I set it "true", I need to call sendScreenName() and then send(). So what is it doing automatically?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474203/is-there-any-code-needed-in-activity-so-that-ga-autoactivitytracking-true-woul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used for tracking your activity:

```
<!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
```

if it is true in **analytics.xml**, it will track all the activities, if we will do the following for each of our acitivity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(context).activityStart(activity);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(context).activityStop(activity);
}
```

this will give results as below in the dashboard of your app in analytics portal:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I found out that if **ga_autoActivityTracking=True**, you just need to make sure that you put **sendScreenName()** in each activity instead of writing separate code for each activity.

Comment: This is incorrect, sendScreenName() is not necessary