# GoogleAnalytics enableAutoActivityTracking not working

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I got the same problem as in this question:

[enableAutoActivityTracking not automatically tracking activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230358/enableautoactivitytracking-not-automatically-tracking-activities)

The problem is that the automated tracking does not work using Google Analytics.

However, calling `enableAutoActivityReports` does not work in my case.

This is the configuration XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--  Google Analytucs property id. -->

<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

<!-- catch and report uncaught exceptions from the app -->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
<screenName name=".LoginActivity">
    Login Activity
</screenName>

</resources>
```

In the application class:

```
private Tracker googleAnalyticsTracker;

public synchronized Tracker getGoogleAnalyticsTracker()
{
    if (googleAnalyticsTracker == null)
    {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.enableAutoActivityReports(this);
        googleAnalyticsTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return googleAnalyticsTracker;
}
```

In the activity's `onCreate`: `((MyApplication) getApplication()).getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();`

However, in the same activity, if I put a manual screen view sending, I DO see it in the GA console. I do it like this:

```
Tracker t = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();
                t.setScreenName("Login Screen");
                t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to report starting and stopping of each activity.

```
public abstract class TrackableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

I couldn't find the documentation that specifies this anymore. I recall I used to follow that. Anyway, from [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#reportActivityStart(android.app.Activity)), this will be required if you want to auto track activity for API lower than 14:

> `public void reportActivityStart (Activity activity)`
>
> If auto activity reports are enabled (see `enableAutoActivityReports(Application)`) on a device running API level 14 or above, this method will be a noop.

Comment: OK it seems to work. But if I need to add code in each and every activity to enable the reporting then where is the "automated" part in "automated screen viewing reporting"? And why would I stop the reporting? Isn't a reporting just a one time thing it sends to the GA server which lets me know that someone is viewing the screen and that's it?

Comment: I think it could be some legacy issue that prevents this to work for API before 14?

Comment: and regarding the second question - why would I stop the reporting? Isn't a reporting just a one time thing it sends to the GA server which lets me know that someone is viewing the screen and that's it?

Comment: I believe it's to differentiate sessions.