# Google Analytics AutoActivityTracking not working Android

Tags: android, android-activity, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am doing google analytics autotrackingactivity in my app.

global_tracker.xml

```
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">-1</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- the Local LogLevel for Analytics -->
    <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>

    <int name="ga_dispatchPeriod">0</int>

    <!-- Treat events as test events and don't send to google -->
    <bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>


    <screenName name="***.***.****.MainActivity">HomeScreen</screenName>

    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-********-*</string>

    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

</resources>
```

Menifest,

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
            android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
```

and in activity,

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }
```

The result for the above in log is ,

```
07-30 16:54:54.545: V/GAV4(10248): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
07-30 16:54:54.545: V/GAV4(10248): Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@3fad587d
07-30 16:54:54.545: V/GAV4(10248): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
07-30 16:54:54.545: V/GAV4(10248): Thread[main,5,main]: bound to service
07-30 16:54:54.555: V/GAV4(10248): Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
07-30 16:54:54.555: I/GAV4(10248): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
07-30 16:54:54.555: V/GAV4(10248): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
```

**Now When I try to send coustom event** , it sends both customEvent and activity track `HomeScreen`

And the logcat shows ,

```
07-30 16:58:12.945: V/GAV4(11158): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
07-30 16:58:12.955: V/GAV4(11158): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
07-30 16:58:12.955: V/GAV4(11158): Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@d809d17
07-30 16:58:12.955: V/GAV4(11158): Thread[main,5,main]: bound to service
07-30 16:58:12.955: V/GAV4(11158): Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
07-30 16:58:12.955: I/GAV4(11158): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
07-30 16:58:12.955: V/GAV4(11158): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
07-30 16:58:12.985: V/GAV4(11158): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
07-30 16:58:12.985: V/GAV4(11158): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
07-30 16:58:12.985: V/GAV4(11158): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
07-30 16:58:12.985: V/GAV4(11158): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  .......
```

**Another thing** , I have tried suggession from here also,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23256722/1602333 , but same result.

So, for sending activity track I had to send event. Is it a bug or I am missing something ?